# Retrieving java output of a function return using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, logfile

I have a java code which returns specific columns from a log file. I am asked to display the returned values using jsp. Since I am new to web programming I am not sure how to go about. If someone could guide me in a step by step manner. 
 The values returned in the java code are in this format:
`Edmess_p_b_actual_stdunit SO`
`Edmess_p_c_dataload    HU`

Comment: Google for "jsp tutorial": http://bit.ly/12HRMPr

Comment: Tht all is done.. the java part is working fine, i now just need to use jsp for printing these values in a tabular form , i.e print the output of the java file in a tabular format. I need to know how to retrieve these values by using jsp.

Comment: Prachi,Those values are beans ?? Are you using JSTL ??

Comment: No they are not beans its just a simple function returning values... I dunno the concept of JSTL tried working with it though.. Is it possible to use just simple scriptlets ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not much clear about the quesion. But what I could understood, in Java there is a method which returns a value. And in JSP you can call the method and print the return value. If this is what your question, then below are the steps...

1) Import the package in jsp using

```
<%@ page import="<your package and class" %>
```

2) If the method is static, you can just use the expression such as:

or scriptlet such as:

```
<% 
           out.println(MyClass.myMethod()); 
 %>
```

3)If the method is instance method, you need to instantiate and call the method as:

```
 <%
           MyClass obj = new Myclass(); 
           out.println(obj.myMethod()); 
 %>
```

However it is just only for beginners to understand the JSP, but don't use in your development code. Always use a business layer who calls those methods and store in a request/session scope. Then print the value in jsp

Answer (score 0):

You should make your Java code a servlet or be called by a servlet.  It should store the information into one or more JavaBeans.  Then from JSP you can use library tags and JSP expressions to retrieve and display the information.

I am assuming you are not using any framework, just plain servlets.  Find out if this is the case and, if not, what's the framework you are supposed to use.

Comment: No framework just plain servlet, i am using a servlet to call the jsp page which in turn imports the java file using the <%@ page import /%> directive

Comment: @PrachiMazumdar  OK.  Then that's the best general guideline I can provide.  I tried to include as many keywords as possible for you too Google/research.  RE JSP page import, you are not really importing the file, but the class.  No Java code is copied into the JSP.  Just "made available".